# SQL - Selecting rows with a column value greater than the rows before it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm curious on the best way to write a query.

I have a table of ids and values. I would like to exclude rows where val is less than val in all of the rows with a lower ID.

I was playing with joining this table to itself on id-1 but that didn't work all of the time.

Some sample data

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE new_temp_table (
    id integer, 
    val integer
);

INSERT INTO new_temp_table (id, val)
VALUES (0, 300),
       (1, 150),
       (2, 100), 
       (3, 200),
       (4, 320),
       (5, 120),
       (6, 220),
       (7, 340);
```

I want the following output.

```
--- id --- val 
--- 0  --- 300
--- 4  --- 320
--- 7  --- 340
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it MySQL or PostgreSQL? Those two are quite different.

Comment: Sorry - PostgreSQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from new_temp_table t
where not exists (
  select 1 from new_temp_table
  where id < t.id and val > t.val
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=9e2557e129c2e3d3171f6bcdb54de2fd).
Results:

```
| id  | val |
| --- | --- |
| 0   | 300 |
| 4   | 320 |
| 7   | 340 |
```

Comment: The query I was writing was quite a bit more complex than the example, but this worked like a charm. What exactly does the `Select 1` do? I appreciate the solution.

Comment: Select 1 means *something*, it could be select 0 or select *. The important part is the statement `not exists`. If that select 1 returns *something* then `not exists` is false or if it does not return anything it is true.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you can use window functions to calculate the max on all the preceding rows and then filter based on that:

```
select id, val
from (select ntt.*, max(val) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as preceding_max
      from new_temp_table ntt
     ) t
where preceding_max is null or val > preceding_max;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5fb93194f987e7970112a1a718e3bc46) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  It is tempting to write this logic without the window specification as:

```
select id, val
from (select ntt.*, max(val) over (order by id) as preceding_max
      from new_temp_table ntt
     ) t
where preceding_max is null or val >= preceding_max;
```

However, this will return rows where the max equals an earlier maximum.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
select
  id, val, max_prev_val
from (
  select
    id,
    val,
    max(val) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
      as max_prev_val
  from new_temp_table
) x
where val >= max_prev_val or max_prev_val is null
```

Result:

```
id           val          max_prev_val  
----------------------------------------
0            300          <null>        
4            320          300           
7            340          320
```